# PHPUnit Explicit Testsuites

Tags: php, phpunit

Is it possible to define a testsuite that does not run by default? It would run only when explicitly called.

The definition could looks something like:

```
<testsuite name="1st">
    <file>test/1stTest.php</file>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="2nd" explicit="true">
    <file>test/2ndTest.php</file>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no, PHPUnit does not support that feature.

As alternatives:

1. You could use two separate config files for PHPUnit, define "2nd" testsuite only in one file and use them with `-c <config_name>.xml` option when you run phpunit.
2. Same base principle as above, but this time with two separate bash files, instead of xml config files. You could call phpunit from each with `--testsuite="<suite_name>"` option.